# Emitting only one of the generated source files

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn, sourcegenerators

I am working with source generators and I want to generate two files containing partial methods. One file will only have defining declarations and the other will have the methods' implementation.

**The question** 
Is there a way to setup the code generation so that one file is available in the project directory (defining declarations file), and for other not to be emitted outside the compilation.

Comment: Are you referring to `EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles` and `CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath`, which applies to all generated files, but you want it to refer to a single file?

Comment: @Youssef13 Pretty much. It would be also great if I could change compilation object from inside the source generator, so I could add/remove sources. Maybe that would give me more flexibility, but that's impossible.

Comment: This is not supported as far as I know. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/56113 is similar, but different. I'll add a comment there for your request.

Comment: Thanks, your proposal would be a good way, too.

Comment: Is the idea here that one file is the auto-generated one the developer never sees, but the other one is a one-time generation, and the developer is editing from there?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Yes, just one little difference is that visible/editable file would also get regenerated every time, but developer's changes would be persisted.
Full info: invisible source is Web API controller with generated actions, and visible source are partial method declarations of those actions where developer could set attributes like [NonAction] and [Route("OverrideRouteUrl")]